# trying to add more ints to one main one

Tags: java, int

hi i'm trying to make a questions game to try my knowledge and abilities 
anyway i'm trying to use an integer to be the points and every question the user
answer gets a special amount of points anyway i was trying to do like this

```
      switch (Ques){ case 1 : //first question about India and where it is in the map
          System.out.println("in what continent India is?");
          Scanner IndiaAns = new Scanner(System.in); //Scanner to receive user answer
          String IndiaAns2 , IndiaAnswer ; //strings to be used to receive user input and matching with the correct ones
          IndiaAns2 = IndiaAns.nextLine(); //Scanner will work here and receive...
          IndiaAnswer = "asia"; //the correct answer here and will be matched with user ones
          if (IndiaAns2 == IndiaAnswer) 
          {int Twopoints = 2; Points = + Twopoints; } else{}

          case 2:
          System.out.println("the Appstore founds in any phone model?");
          Scanner Appstore =new Scanner(System.in);
          String AppstoreAns1 ,AppstoreAns2; //strings saving 
          AppstoreAns1 = Appstore.nextLine(); //Scanner
          AppstoreAns2 = "iphone"; //matching with user answer
          if (AppstoreAns1 == AppstoreAns2)
          { int Threepoints = 3; Points = +Threepoints;} else { Points = +0;}
```

.. there's two other case and the points integer is in not in the code sample area is in upper line any ways if the full codes its necessary i'll put it

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Off topic to the question, but you need a `break` at the bottom of every `case` of your `switch`

Comment: how do i add more than one integer to main one? something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your code ,

```
  if (IndiaAns2 == IndiaAnswer) 
          {int Twopoints = 2; Points = + Twopoints; } else{}
```

Should be something like

```
 if(indiaAns2.equals(indiaAnswer)){
  points += QUESTION_1_POINTS;
 }
```

Where `QUESTION_1_POINTS`  is defined as a constant like `

```
public static final int  QUESTION_1_POINTS =2;
```

There you are assigning to `points` variable , `points + QUESTION_1_POINTS`.

```
points += someInteger   --> points = points + someInteger
```

Some advices,

1) Follow [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) , variable names start with lower-case

2) For object comparision always use `equals()` instead of `==`
Example:

Change

```
if (IndiaAns2 == IndiaAnswer)
```

to:

```
if (indiaAns2.equals(indiaAnswer))
```

3) You need to make switch statement

```
switch(condition){
case 1:
//code
break;
case 2:
//code 
break;
default:// some code;
}
```

Comment: Same as other answer, this **does not cover** OP's problem, you are just giving advices to the current code.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza i edited

Comment: Reposting a comment in the now deleted answer: IMO this question is unclear since is about adding an int value to another. Note OP's comment: how do i add more than one integer to main one? something like that. Now, how do you think this answer **really** solves OP's main problem?

Comment: he wants to use an "acumulador" , i think solves his issue about amounting in `points` variable, may be i misunderstood the question

Comment: Yes, probably that's what OP wants/needs, but in its current state this answer doesn't provide a direct answer to the main question. By the way, "acumulador" in English is known as *counter*.

Comment: and `contador` ? i edited to make it clear, my english is bad luiggi xD

Comment: Contador = counter. By the way, my English writing/speaking is not the best either, but at least try to use a tool like an online translator or english dictionary to enhance both your English knowledge and your Q/As in this site.

Comment: i want to make a simple question game wheres the user answer questions and earning points then showing him the points at the end but when i use the same code up there it gives me 0 points .. and the computer having a random number between 1-11 and matching with my points and knowing who wins

Comment: that's solved my problem thanks.. you remembered me how

Comment: okay i did and mark it thanks for help sorry i wasn't here